# Python, Sympy: How to output sympy expression as Python function?

Tags: python, function, numpy, sympy, symbolic-math

The [lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) function of Sympy can only convert our expression to the lambda function.

```
x, y = symbols('x y')
expr = x + 2*y
f = lambdify(x, expr)
```

But how to output the expression as a Python function? something like:

```
def expr(x, y):
    return x + 2*y
```

Or is that possible to auto-generate a python script file `expr.py` for our function expression using Sympy?

In short, need to achieve what `matlabFunction` does in Matlab ([Convert symbolic to matlab function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html))

Comment: There's a section in the sympy docs about printing systems.

Comment: Try `print(inspect.getsource(f))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if that is what you are looking for, but sympy has the [octave (matlab) code printing option](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#module-sympy.printing.octave).

Here a quick example of what it does:

```
import sympy as sym
x,y = sym.symbols('x y')
expr = x + 2*y
expr2 = sym.sin(x) + sym.I*sym.exp(y)
sym.pprint(expr) #prints nice human readable output
sym.pprint(sym.printing.octave.octave_code(expr))   #prints octave (matlab) compatible output
sym.pprint(expr2)
sym.pprint(sym.printing.octave.octave_code(expr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols('x y')
expr = x + 2*y
func = lambdify([x,y], expr)
f=func(1,2)
```

output: 5

not sure whether this is what you want.